# When is a module shown as 'Unsupported' in the list of available updates?

Tags: updating

In the available updates, there are few modules with the note *unsupported*.

What does that note actually mean?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/251466

Comment: @Clive If the OP is referring to what the updates page show when updating from the UI, that page doesn't list abandoned modules.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Is there a difference? The linked page seems to suggest they're the same thing (or maybe at least equivalent). I couldn't find any docs for unsupported that didn't mention abandoned too

Comment: @Clive _Unsupported_ has a broader meaning that could mean something else. Last time I checked, the _abandoned_ status was not reported from the update page, but it could be they changed that. I am checking the code.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8, that string is output from [`UpdateManagerUpdate::buildForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21update%21src%21Form%21UpdateManagerUpdate.php/function/UpdateManagerUpdate%3A%3AbuildForm/8.5.x), which contains the following code.

```
  case UPDATE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
    $type = 'unsupported';
    $entry['title'] .= ' ' . $this->t('(Unsupported)');
    $entry['#weight'] = -1;
    break;
```

The [`UpdateManagerInterface::NOT_SUPPORTED`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21update%21src%21UpdateManagerInterface.php/constant/UpdateManagerInterface%3A%3ANOT_SUPPORTED/8.5.x) constant simply means the current release is no longer supported by the project maintainer. The maintainer doesn't intend to further develop the module code, not even to fix security issues. If you look at the project page, you will notice the following note, given under the *Project information* section.

> Unsupported
>   Not supported (i.e. abandoned), and no longer being developed. Learn more about [dealing with unsupported (abandoned) projects](https://www.drupal.org/node/251466)

As such, the update page is suggesting to find another module with the same, or similar, features because, in case of security issues, chances are nobody is going to fix them, and the module would need to be uninstalled, to avoid site issues.

In Drupal 7, a similar string is output from [`theme_update_status_label()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21update%21update.report.inc/function/theme_update_status_label/7.x), which contains the following code.

```
case UPDATE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
  return '<span class="not-supported">' . t('Not supported!') . '</span>';
```

The [`UPDATE_NOT_SUPPORTED`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21update%21update.module/constant/UPDATE_NOT_SUPPORTED/7.x) constant has the same meaning saw for Drupal 8, and it was introduced in Drupal 6.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't say which version of Drupal it is about, and for D6 you don't get such "`unsupported`" (only a variation of it, something like "`not supported!`". So assuming this question is about D8, you probably see a message containing (exactly) "`unsupported`" as in [this image](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/Update_My_Site_-_2017-10-13_14.07.12.png).

If my (educated) guess is correct, you possibly get such message for some module which is no ***`longer available for download`***. At least that's what is mentioned also in the linked image. Apart from this, be aware of [this D8.6 issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/961060) ... current status "needs review".

PS: even though I can't find a relevant contributed project with status "abandonded" (in the list of modules I ever used), I doubt you get such "unsupported" message for contributed projects with such project status.